# Proper Map Equivalent Definitions

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, pullback

Let $f: X\to Y$ be a map between topological spaces. $f$ is called proper when every preimage $f^{-1}(K)$ of every compact $K \subset Y$ is also compact.

On wiki's [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_map) I found following statements:

> If X is Hausdorff and Y is locally compact Hausdorff then proper is equivalent to universally closed.

Remark:A map is universally closed if for any topological space $Z$ the map $f × id_Z : X × Z → Y × Z$  is closed.

> In the case that $Y$ is Hausdorff, this is equivalent to requiring that for any map $Z → Y$  the pullback $X ×_Y Z → Z$  be closed, as follows from the fact that $X ×_Y Z$  is a closed subspace of $X × Z$.

Does anybody know a recomendable source where these two statements are rigorously proved?

Comment: You can find the answer you are looking for in : The Stacks project (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/005M, Characterizing proper maps)